# MongoDB + PHP No concurrent

Tags: php, performance, mongodb, concurrency

I have an application developed in PHP using MongoDB to attack database. My problem is that on some occasions, to make a query, takeslong and the following error is thrown:
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to MongoCollection::__construct() must be an instance of MongoDB, null given in..

Even if I open two equal browsers, if I access the application in each them until not one of the browsers will not end the query, the other does not It begins .. Why is not concurrent?..

I use MongoDB 2.6.5, PHP 5.3.3-7 y PHP MongoDB Driver 1.6.8.

Example code:

```
//Function call from Application
<php>
    //Conectamos con la BBDD
    $db = connectBbdd("modelo");

    $mongoNci = $_SESSION["sesion_nci"];
    $collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'users');
    $js = "function() {
         return this.Nci == '$mongoNci';
    }";
    $cursor = $collection->find(array('$where' => $js));
    $array = iterator_to_array($cursor);
</php>

<php>
    function connectBbdd($dbname){
        Mongo::setPoolSize(10);
        $m = new MongoClient("mongodb://ipremote:port");
        $db = $m->$dbname;

        return $db;
    }
</php>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the error message, it could be that the number of connections exceeded the pool size of 10 and the connection is rejected.

Since your queries are slow, it is also possible that some of these queries are still running - taking up some of the connections.

About concurrency, I am not 100% sure but it may be because the load on the machine may be too high to process the queries concurrently.